# Implementation of Trie using ES6 class javaScript

Tags: javascript, class, oop, data-structures, trie

I am being generated same answer everytime for different test cases. In my code in which I tried to create Trie data structure to store and retrieve the highest priority of strings for subsequent queries. For eg. I thought of creating a search engine type pattern.

Please do help me with my problem-

Input -

hackerearth 10

hackerman 5

```
class TrieNode {
  constructor(priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
    this.children = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
      this.children.push(null)
    }
  }
}

class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.root = new TrieNode(-1);
  }

  createNode(priority) {
    let obj = new TrieNode(priority)
    return obj;
  }

  max(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
      return a;
    }
    return b;
  }

  insertNode(word, priority) {
    let ptr = this.root;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (ptr.children[word[i] - 'a'] != null) {
        ptr.children[word[i] - 'a'].priority = this.max(ptr.children[word[i] - 'a'].priority, priority)
      } else {
        ptr.children[word[i] - 'a'] = this.createNode(priority)
      }
      ptr = ptr.children[word[i] - 'a']
    }
  }
  checkNode(word) {
    let ptr = this.root;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (ptr.children[word[i] - 'a'] === null) {
        return -1;
      }
      ptr = ptr.children[word[i] - 'a']
    }
    return ptr.priority;
  }

}

let a = new Trie();
a.insertNode("hackerearth", 10);
a.insertNode("hackerman", 5);
console.log(a.root.children['h' - 'a'])
console.log(a.checkNode("hackerf"))
```

The result is always the same:

```
TrieNode {
  priority: 10,
  children: [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    NaN: TrieNode { priority: 10, children: [Array] }
  ]
}
10
```

Comment: Note: you can use `this.children = Array(25).fill(null)` to set up the array

Comment: Thank You,@epascarello but the main issue is with the whole trie data structure that i am trying to implement

Comment: Your subtracting strings which makes no sense. I assume you want the characterCode based on 0 for A? `"hello".split('').map(x => x.charCodeAt(0) - "a".charCodeAt(0))`

Answer (score 1):

You can not just subtract strings. You need to convert them to the character code. `charCodeAt` will do it.

```js
class TrieNode {
  constructor(priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
    this.children = [] // I would not initialize
  }
}

class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.root = new TrieNode(-1);
  }

  createNode(priority) {
    let obj = new TrieNode(priority)
    return obj;
  }

  max(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
      return a;
    }
    return b;
  }

  insertNode(word, priority) {
    let ptr = this.root;
    const a = "a".charCodeAt(0); // store value of a
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      const index = word[i].charCodeAt(0) - a // calculate difference
      if (ptr.children[index] != null) {
        ptr.children[index].priority = this.max(ptr.children[index].priority, priority)
      } else {
        ptr.children[index] = this.createNode(priority)
      }
      ptr = ptr.children[index]
    }
  }
  checkNode(word) {
    let ptr = this.root;
    const a = "a".charCodeAt(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      // just check for false
      if (!ptr.children[word[i].charCodeAt(0) - a]) {
        return -1;
      }
      ptr = ptr.children[word[i].charCodeAt(0) - a]
    }

    return ptr.priority;
  }

}

let a = new Trie();
a.insertNode("hackerearth", 10);
a.insertNode("hackerman", 5);
console.log(a.checkNode("hacker"))
console.log(a.checkNode("hackere"))
console.log(a.checkNode("hackerm"))
console.log(a.checkNode("hackerf"))
```

You could also just use an object instead of an array and just use the character as the property key.

```js
class TrieNode {
  constructor(priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
    this.children = {}
  }
}

class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.root = new TrieNode(-1);
  }

  createNode(priority) {
    let obj = new TrieNode(priority)
    return obj;
  }

  max(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
      return a;
    }
    return b;
  }

  insertNode(word, priority) {
    let ptr = this.root;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      const index = word[i]
      if (ptr.children[index] != null) {
        ptr.children[index].priority = this.max(ptr.children[index].priority, priority)
      } else {
        ptr.children[index] = this.createNode(priority)
      }
      ptr = ptr.children[index]
    }
  }
  checkNode(word) {
    let ptr = this.root;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      // just check for false
      if (!ptr.children[word[i]]) {
        return -1;
      }
      ptr = ptr.children[word[i]]
    }

    return ptr.priority;
  }

}

let a = new Trie();
a.insertNode("hackerearth", 10);
a.insertNode("hackerman", 5);
console.log(a.checkNode("hacker"))
console.log(a.checkNode("hackere"))
console.log(a.checkNode("hackerm"))
console.log(a.checkNode("hackerf"))
```